# How to wrap the text in 2 lines on Internet Explorer and firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-11

I am wrapping the text in 2 lines . On Google Chrome it's wrapping in 2 lines  using the code 
    overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;  max-width: 100%; white-space: normal;

But this code is not working on Internet Explore and Firefox.

Please help me

Comment: can you update your code in fiddle

Comment: in css :.unitAddressList ul li>div.address{width:11%; margin-right: 1%; margin-top: 8px;overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;  max-width: 100%; white-space: normal; text-overflow: ellipsis;  line-height: 20px;}

Answer (score 0):

Have your used word-wrap? Try this.
[Hope this helps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531186(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes Kranthi , but word wrap is not supporting IE-11 and FF

Answer (score 0):

can you copy paste this code to your html page ,this one worked for me , text will wrap all broswers

```css
.main_box {
    float:left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.main_box p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_box">
   <p>jasdlfjlasjdfsajdfjsadfjlsajdflsjdfjsldfjlsjdflsjdfljsadlfjsldjflsajdflasjdfjsaldj</p>
</div>
```